# PHP Upload File AND Write TXT File

Tags: php

This SHD work ... no idea why.
When user submits form, uploads the file to ../images/ and writes that file name to a text file. It does not upload the file and it blanks out the txt file which I assume means the upload fails.

```
$img_name = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
$upload_file = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], "../images/" . $img_name);

$log_avatar = fopen('../archive/avatar.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($log_avatar, $img_name);
fclose($log_avatar);

header("location:user.php");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to write the name of the uploaded file to text file use "a+" instead of "w+" 
the difference between them is

"w+" opens the file for reading and writing and place the file pointer at the beginning of the file

"a+" opens the file for reading and writing and place the file pointer at the end of the file

```
$log_avatar = fopen('../archive/avatar.txt', 'a+');
```

also you can add line break using PHP_EOL

```
fwrite($log_avatar, $img_name.PHP_EOL);
```

that is what makes the text file get empty

about upload files there is nothing wrong in your code. 
but i think you are have error in your html form because filename is blank

make sure you set the form enctype Attribute to "multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="up.php">
```

and using the correct input name in your upload script

Comment: Ugh, it was the "enctype" ... I forgot to place it in the form ... and knew better. Many thank yous for refreshing my memory. Stupid mistake.